# NodeJS authentication middleware fails after successful login

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

I have an angular app running on localhost:8000 and a node express api with passport authentication on localhost:3000.

After the user login the server returns a successful response but when I try to call other services it fails on the authentication middleware. It doesn't make sense since the login was successful. The user should be authenticated!

Using postman I was able to call authenticated services successfully, but when I make calls from my angular application it return that the user is not authenticated, even after a successful login.

Authentication middleware:

```
exports.isAuthenticated = (request, response, next) => {
  if (!request.isAuthenticated()) return next(createError(401, 'Você não está autorizado.'));
  next();
};
```

When I move the api to a real domain everything works. I thinks it's something related to the localhost x localhost connection but don't know what. I need both applications running on the same domain since it's a requirement for my Facebook application.

I'm on this problem for weeks, tried different solutions but nothing works. I don't know more what to do!

The request and response settings:
[image]

Comment: I'm confused, you are sending a cookie or session token in your request from your angular app correct?  In the snippet you provided, how can you call `request.isAuthenticated()` inside of the middleware function? `module.isAuthenticated()` should be in the middleware chain somewhere.

Comment: I send the Facebook token on login since I'm using [Facebook token strategy](https://github.com/drudge/passport-facebook-token) and chain the authentication middleware like this `app.get('/subscriptions', passportConfig.isAuthenticated, subscriptionController.getList)`. The login works, but when I try to call services after the login it always fails on the authentication middleware.

Comment: make sure token or cookie has been parsed on subsequent request made to the server.

Comment: I checked the request and response, there's no token or cookie been parsed on subsequent requests. I edited my answer with a print of the request and response settings for you to confirm. Is that right?

Comment: You should read about the [`withCredentials` option](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Cross-site XHR requests won't, by default, pass credentials like cookies